# how to store user data in ios firebase with swift 4

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

```
@IBAction func usernameContinueBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    if let email = emailFieldSignUp.text, let password = passwordFieldSignUp.text {

        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            else{
                let userData = ["firstName": self.firstNameSignUpField.text! as String ,
                                "lastName": self.lastNameSignUpField.text! as String,
                                "username": self.usernameSignUpField.text! as String
                                ]
                let ref = Database.database().reference()
                ref.child("users").setValue(userData)

                print("Sign Up Successfully.")
                self.presentFeedPage()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hi, I'm really new to xcode. I would like to know how this code can be fixed such that when a user signs up with email, they can store their first name, last name and username in firebase database.

Answer (score 2):

To save the user data, you need to initialize the database first. You do so in `viewDidLoad()`

First, add this to your `viewDidLoad()` function:

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ref = Database.database().reference()

   // ... //
}
```

After that, to store the user in their own record ID, You need to specify:

```
self.ref.child("users").child(user.uid).setValue(userData)
```

Or:

```
@IBAction func usernameContinueBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {

if let email = emailFieldSignUp.text, let password = passwordFieldSignUp.text {

    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        else{
            let userData = ["firstName": self.firstNameSignUpField.text! as String ,
                            "lastName": self.lastNameSignUpField.text! as String,
                            "username": self.usernameSignUpField.text! as String
                            ]


            self.ref.child("users").child(user.uid).setValue(userData)
            print("Sign Up Successfully.")
            self.presentFeedPage()
        }
    }
}
```

}

I also refer you to their docs, I love firebase for two things, the speed, and their docs.

[Read and Write Data on iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write)